# Switching between 3D formats

Tags: video-conversion, 3d

How can I convert a 3D video file from one format to another? Let's say I want to convert a side-by-side formatted file to frame sequential.

Comment: In Super User, and all the StackExchange sites, shopping or product recommendations are considered off topic and open ended, and sometimes even too localized. Try to reword your question in a way that you are not asking for products, but more of processes; this will help keep it on topic

Comment: @Luke I have rephrased my question, and would very much like it to be reopened if possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found [Bino](http://bino3d.org), which is a multiplatform free video player which supports following input/output modes (and switching between them):

Input layouts:

> - Monoscopic (2D) video
> - Left and right view in separate video streams and/or files
> - Left and right view side by side (optionally with half width)
> - Left and right view on top of each other (optionally with half height)
> - Left and right view in alternating rows

Output techniques:

> - Anaglyph glasses (red/cyan, green/magenta, amber/blue). This works with every display.
>     Bino uses the high-quality Dubois method to produce anaglyph images. This gives far better results than the usual full-color and half-color methods.
> - Left and right view side by side (used by some 3D displays)
> - Left and right view on top of each other (used by some 3D displays)
> - Left and right view in alternating rows or columns (used by some 3D displays)
> - OpenGL quad-buffered stereo (only available with some graphics cards)

Comment: It seems to play 3D video files nicely – but any idea on how to save the output? It says it uses ffmpeg libraries but I had no luck using `ffmpeg` cli myself for that purpose. One problem was that it would halve the fps when using the stereo filter `-vf stereo3d=ar:sbsl` to get a left-right version. This seems to fit the notion that it does not know about MVC codec and ignores the second frame part.